# What is the host key of Windows 7 Virtual PC and where can you change it?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

Does anyone know which key is the host key of Windows 7 Virtual PC and where I could change it to a different one? Before Windows 7 the host key was changed in the option menu of Virtual PC but the new version is integrated into the explorer so there is no option menu for Virtual PC.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/27017/what-is-the-host-key-of-windows-7-virtual-pc-and-where-can-you-change-it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same like default in Hyper-V: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.